# Is there any way to change color of pushButton when a condition(s) satisfies?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, pyqt5

I am building an app using Pyqt. It has a few input boxes and a submit button. What I want is that my button should only become active(change colour) when all input boxes are filled.
Can I do this ?

```
self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(35, 610, 541, 31))
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setPointSize(12)
font.setBold(True)
font.setWeight(75)
self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
```

Comment: Do you just want to change the color, or do you want to change its enabled/disabled state? Those things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: One way would be to add connects to all the input boxes that go to a function which checks all the boxes are are filled and then enables the button if so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the idea would be to get the text from all the QTextEdits using
*.toPlainText()* and color the button if they all are not empty
You should use a thread for checking that.
Here is a quick example of what i mean...

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import threading

global textEdit0
global textEdit1
global textEdit2
global textEdit3
global buttonToColor


def check_input_thread():
    while True:
        if (textEdit0.toPlainText() != "" and
                textEdit1.toPlainText() != "" and
                textEdit2.toPlainText() != "" and
                textEdit3.toPlainText() != ""):
            buttonToColor.setStyleSheet("background-color : green")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
textEdit0 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(widget);
textEdit1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(widget);
textEdit2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(widget);
textEdit3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(widget);
buttonToColor = QtWidgets.QPushButton(widget);
textEdit0.move(0, 0)
textEdit1.move(0, 50)
textEdit2.move(0, 100)
textEdit3.move(0, 150)
buttonToColor.move(0, 200)

thread = threading.Thread(target=check_input_thread)
thread.start();



widget.show();
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why not use a QTimer, or at least Timer from the threading module if you're going this route to solve the problem?  Setting a property on the button with an accompanying stylesheet would probably be a cleaner solution.